# Python: How to efficiently implement large symmetric array with many empty entries

Tags: python, arrays, list, size, memory-efficient

I am using a very large 2-dimensional square array whose entries are lists of integers. This is not written in stone, but say it's a w by w array, with w=15000, and each entry is a list of integers, with random size from 0 to 400.
This has two characteristics:

1. It is symmetric
2. Many of its entries are empty lists, including the ones on the diagonal

Right now, I am only taking advantage of the first part and implement it like this pseudocode:

```
F=[ [ [] for i in range(w)] for j in range(w) ] # Initiate a blank w X w array
for i in range(w):
    for j in range(i):
    If (condition):
        F[i][j] = [A list of integers]
```

Then in the end, I assign the rest of the values as follows:

```
for i in range(w):
    for j in range(w):
        F[i][j]=F[i][j] # Reference, thus size of F does not increase much
```

---

I am not an experienced programmer, and I'm feeling this approach is probably not very efficient. In particular, I feel that I am not taking advantage of the fact that many entries are empty.

Can I have a more efficient list F such that it doesn't occupy any space for the entries that end up being empty?

Mind that it is still important that I have the "coordinates" x, y assigned correctly.

Comment: Sparse arrays in numpy maybe?

Comment: There are a number of different "sparse array" data structures, which have different tradeoffs. You're going to have to do a bit of research, because no one can tell you which one is "best" in general.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you switch from native Python lists of lists to NumPy arrays, you can use [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html) to handle most of the data structures that are clunky to write in Python.

Comment: Thank you abarnet. Mind that the entries are lists of integers themselves; my first impression is that the scipy structures that you mention here are only for numerical data. But I will do some more research

Comment: @geo909: A numpy/scipy array/matrix can hold `dtype=object`, which can be anything you want.

Comment: Do you know how sparse it's likely to be? If it's 50% occupied with entries that are on average 200 items long, then the actual data is big (11.25 billion values), and the space "wasted" on empty and symmetric entries is pretty small compared with the total. So probably you might as well stick with what you have. If it's 0.01% occupied then a dictionary or a custom "sparse matrix" data structure is more likely to make a practical difference. If it's 99.75% occupied and only 0.25% of entries are empty, forget about saving space for them, it's trivial.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answers. I'm looking into it and running some experiments to realize how many empty spaces I have. It seems that most of the entries are non-empty, so probably I'll just leave things as is.

Comment: @geo909: Another thing to consider here is that 225M Python lists of average length 200 is nothing to sneeze at. Using a 15K*15K*400 NumPy array might save you more in time and/or space than you waste by fixing the third dimension at 400 instead of having it vary from 0-400. Also, what's the range of your integers? 11.25G `int32` objects are half the size of 11.25G 8-byte pointers even if they're all 0, and if they're spread out evenly, you're also saving up to 4G 24-byte `int` objecs.

Comment: Thanks. I may have to revisit my strategy and use numpy. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to store sparse matrices, and [Wikipedia is a good place to start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix). Without knowing what you're planning to do with these, nobody can tell you which one to use.

For example, the Dictionary of Keys design is very simple to build in Python:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in range(w):
    for j in range(w):
        if condition:
            d[i, j] = [a list of integers]
```

That's it. Now, to retrieve or change a value later:

```
value = d[i, j]
d[i, j].append(3)
```

But if you ever want to, say, iterate all of the non-empty rows in order, then all of the non-empty columns of each row in order, this is going to be terribly inefficient. The naive solution would be to just loop over every i and j and look up `d[i, j]`, but that's going to allocate a new empty list to fill in every single position. You could instead sort the keys, but that can be slow as well. You could keep around coordinate lists sorted in both orders, alongside the dictionary—but at that point, the dictionary is just adding extra overhead over just sticking a reference to the value in each coordinate list.

So, there are other alternatives that are better for different uses.

If you're willing to use NumPy/SciPy arrays, [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html) handles 2D sparse arrays. Of course they're *normally* arrays of numbers, but you can use `dtype=object` with most of the types (although that does mean that "empty" slots will have `None` instead of `[]`, and there are also some odd limitations on what works in those cases). (There's also some documentation somewhere (sorry, no link…) that explains how the sparse matrices are implemented and how to do the equivalent in pure Python/NumPy, which you could use to create a WxWx400 sparse array of ints.)